# How to inject @Value properties from application.properties to @InjectMocks in springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

**BatchService.java**

```java
@Service
public class BatchService {

   
    @Value("#{${priority.mapping}}")
    public Map<String, String> priorMap;

    @Autowired
    private Repo payload;
    
    public boolean createAndAddBatches(){

        for (String priority: priorMap.keySet()) {
       // code
        }
    }
}
```

**BatchServiceTest.java**

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class BatchServiceTest {

    @Value("#{${priority.mapping}}")
    private static Map<String, String> priorMap;


    @Mock
    private Repo repoMock;

    @InjectMocks
    private BatchService batchService;

    @BeforeClass
    @PrepareForTest({LogManager.class})
    public static void setup() {
        
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(BatchService.class, "priorMap", priorMap);
    }
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder (in unnamed module @0xc3cdf38) cannot access class jdk.xml.internal.SecuritySupport (in module java.xml) because module java.xml does not export jdk.xml.internal to unnamed module @0xc3cdf38
```

**application.properties**

```
priority.mapping = {'first':'1','second':'2','third':'3'}
```

is there a way to inject the hashmap from the properties file to BatchService? It throws error when I used *ReflectionTestUtils.setField(BatchService.class, "priorMap", priorMap);*

Answer (score 0):

Don't use BatchService.class, use the instance you are testing:

```java
@BeforeEach
public void init() throws Exception {
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(batchService, "priorMap", "value you want to inject");
}
```

Comment: Thank for replying. Tried but it gives error java.lang.NullPointerException at this line           ```for (String priority: priorMap.keySet())```